# Device statistics with given hardware accessories, sensors, etc?

Tags: android, configuration, keyboard, hardware

There's an [Android dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) that provides statistics by operating system, screen sizes, and densities.

However, I'd like to get at data like devices with physical keyboards, front cameras, etc.  Is such information collected and published somewhere?

[image]

Comment: This question is not a good fit for stackoverflow as it isn't a programming question. I don't recall ever encountering such statistics for the `Play Store`.

Comment: @Luksprog I thought it was implicit that the reason for the collection of this data and the reason the Android Dashboard is published on the Android Developers site is that this information would be helpful in deciding what devices and sensors to target for development.

Comment: The distribution of android versions is very important(because the APIs will have big changes from one version o another), other statistics would be nice but I doubt they will get implemented. The android team would want you to build your app to cover as much devices as you can and not drop support(for example) for phones with physical keyboards just because you see that they have a small market share. Also, you have the chance of supporting/excluding most devices based on various hardware elements.